# How to fetch all 3 level categories in magento?

Tags: php, magento

I want to show all top level categories and its respective 2 level of subcategories. for example 
Root category(id=3)

```
-Electronics
  --Computers
   ---Dell
   ---Samsung
   ---Accer

 -Games Movies and Musics
  --Games
   ---Pc Games
   ---Mobile Games
```

Here **Electronics** and **Games Movies and Musics** is top level categories
I don't want to display root category, only from top level categories i.e from **electronics** and **Games Movies and Musics**

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
$category_id = 'Electronics category id'
$children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($category_id);
foreach ($children as $category) {
echo $category->getName();
}
```

Update:
You can keep looping through them like this

```
$category_id = 'Electronics category id';
    $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($category_id);
    foreach ($children as $category) {
        echo '<h1>'.$category->getName().'</h1>';
        if($category->getChildren()){
            $childrensChildren = $category->getChildren();
            foreach($childrensChildren as $ChildCategory){
                echo '<h2>'.$ChildCategory->getName().'</h2>';
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: but how can I set electronics category id ..its dynamic it can be anything. here electronics is subcategory of root category having id 3  and computer is subcategory of electronics consequently dell is subcategory of computer. so only we can set the id of root category.

Comment: To find out the category id log into the backend and go to Catalog -> Manager Categories and find and click the required category in this case Electronics. On the top you will see the ID

Comment: thanks for replying me again. I know how to find category id. your code is only showing me all categories placed in root category. its not showing me its subcategories. what i want by using root category id i have to show electronics then all subcategories of electronics i.e computer and finally by using computer i have to show its subcategory i.e dell, samsung sony etc.

Comment: it not showing subcategories it only showing all top level category. please see my updated question. i hope u will understand my exact need

Comment: You need to add another foreach loop inside it, as many loops as sub categories you need. Basically at each level get the category children and loop through them.